# Can I use an American power strip in a European outlet?

Tags: voltage, mains

All my devices can take 110-240 V. I need to connect six of them and I only have a European outlet (any type) and an American power strip (with plug adapter).

Considering voltage will arc at 1 kV/mm, it seems unlikely that there would be any problem as long as it's a "dumb" power strip i.e. just branching wires and that's it.

But if the power strip is "smart" in any way, I doubt it would work.

Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: If your devices have been designed and built to be used with 110 V in America and with 230 V in Europe, they should be delivered with different power cables for America and Europe. So use the devices with the European cables and an European power strip. Everything used is rated for 230 V then. –

Comment: "Seems unlikely" is also the basis for Russian Roulette. Are you willing to play that game as well?

Comment: Even if the [branching wires] were a valid distance apart for 240VAC, this is ignoring the construction materials.  The receptacle insulation could be thinner or different for 120VAC operation (to save cost.)  Or a plethora of other reasons.  Using any electric device beyond it's ratings is asking for trouble.  The manufacturer spent a lot of money to certify *those* ratings specifically.

Comment: Most power strips also have some surge suppression circuitry in them, and that may blow up if you give it a constant "surge" of 240 V.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Insulation ratings, creepage distances, etc are all designed for specific voltages.  The power strip is expecting a certain input voltage "guaranteed" by the plug.  It might "work" with a plug adapter but it is certainly not something I recommend and I imagine any insurance claims arising from any mishaps would be declined not to mention the danger of someone inadvertently plugging a 120V-only device into your 240V NEMA 5-15 power strip.